# Getting a facebook access token

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I'm developing an android app where you can see the photoalbums of a facebook user. I have a solution where it works when I add an acces token to a *HttpGet Request* which was manually generated via [facebook developer tools](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer).

Whats the proper way to create such an access tokens via android/java? Is there a way to get one without using the *facebook android sdk*?

Comment: Which version of the Facebook SDK are you using? Is it version 3 or lower?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment, let me make a couple of suggestions. Before I get to that, let me also clarify a few things on your current scenario.

The way you are currently pulling in data by manually putting in the `Access Token` will work **as long as the Access Token is valid**. Access Token have an expiration. After that, a new Access Token is assigned. As long as it works, it all good. Your app will work just fine, your users will be able to see the photoalbums as per the query.

The difficulty will start when the Access Token expires. Facebook does not intimate you when it expires and therefore, you have no way of knowing when to take corrective action.

Now, because you are hard coding the Access Token in your `Activity`, every time the Access Token expires, you will have to push and update with the updated Access Token.

You can see, hopefully, where I am going with this.

**The suggestions:**

*One:*

Keep things the way they are and you will have to, I suspect, when the Access Token expires, face the ire of your users (read, negative ratings and comments). Not to mention, having to push updates where Users will not see any changes, additions or improvements just to fix an expired Access Token. I don't see how this will be a productive exercise.

*Two:*

The simplest thing to do, is to integrate the Facebook SDK in your App, even if it sounds too a big deal for something as simple as an Access Token. The immediate benefit (for your users) of this is, your Users will always have a seamless experience with your App. And for you, it will save a lot of headaches that I have already spoken of earlier.

**The Bottom Line**

There is no alternative to getting dynamic Access Tokens without making the use of the SDK relevant to the platform. In this case, [[image]android](/questions/tagged/android). You can continue to use the same method of pulling in data, but with a *dynamic* Access Token.

To know more about Access Token and to get an idea of how they work, visit this link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/access-tokens-and-types/

Comment: thanks for your answer!
you say, i can continue using same methods for pulling in data. but i can't find a way to get something like an access-token object from which i could get the access-token-string. also i'm new to facebook sdk then...
do you have any ideas to get this working for me?

Comment: @MatthiasTroja: Exactly. You can continue to use it if you are willing to face a few difficulties. The better thing to in my opinion, would be to integrate the SDK and make things generally easier for everyone. To get started with integrating the Facebook SDK with Android, visit this link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/

Comment: please can help me please in this part,i need to view last 15 post of specific facebook page in my app and i don't need to make facebook login how can i get access token

Comment: @AmalKronz you can't. Users need to permit your application to access their Facebook data. Without this, you cannot get an access token. And without an access token, you cannot access any Facebook data. You can _possibly_ try _scraping_ the data off the Facebook page. But that's not a _legitimate_ way of accessing data.

Comment: i develop app for company and it request to view their own facebook page post on this app how can i make this without using facebook login

Comment: @AmalKronz: You cannot!

Answer (score -1):

have you read the documentation of the new SDK? it does it automatically.

```
public class MainActivity extends FacebookActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      this.openSession();
   }

    @Override
    protected void onSessionStateChange(SessionState state, Exception exception) {
      // user has either logged in or not ...
      if (state.isOpened()) {
        // make request to the /me API
        Request request = Request.newMeRequest(
          this.getSession(),
          new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
            // callback after Graph API response with user object
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
              if (user != null) {
                TextView welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
                welcome.setText("Hello " + user.getName() + "!");
              }
            }
          }
        );
        Request.executeBatchAsync(request);
      }
    }
}
```